# Missing flag option "Should be closed" resulted in rejected flag "Please familiarise yourself with standard flags"

Tags: support, flags, off-topic, declined-flags, flag-dialog

On meta.stackexchange about an hour or so ago, this happened. Normaly encountering an off-topic post I would flag as "Should be closed" which directs me to a number of options: Blatantly off topic, should be on another site on the network etc.. but this appeared as the flagging options:

[image]

Of course when I flagged for mod attention stating "off-topic" as the reason, my flag was declined with this:

[image]

Has one of the "standard flags" - the "Should be closed" option been removed, or is this a quirk of some days in early april?

Comment: It's now hidden under Needs Improvement->A community specific reason.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough, thought I'd missed a memo or something.

Comment: I was expecting some announcement here on MSE regarding the change.

Comment: You weren't the only one to miss the memo ;) I was the one to decline your flag, I had no idea there had been a change that confused users and led to that flag. Or that the help center wouldn't clarify things. My apologies!

Comment: A UI change no one asked for which was not announced has already led to confusion and rejected flags. Who could have predicted...

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right there:

[image]

'needs improvement' is the new 'should be closed'; the options are still listed in the same order. Choose 'A community-specific reason', which is the new 'off-topic':

[image]

The 'blatantly off-topic' option will be displayed, though I usually choose the first option:

[image]

Comment: Now *that's* a freehand circle. Take notes, people.

Comment: Needs improvement implies improvement would be possible, which just isn't true for a lot of off-topic questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii yeah, I just realised this. The wording is weird - for example, if a question is posted here instead of on another stack (happens A LOT), then there is no real improvement you can do to make it appropriate for Meta SE.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select ***Needs Improvement***.  This will bring up a new set of options (most of which should be familiar):

[image: Needs improvement]

---

Selecting ***A community-specific reason*** then gives the options you were looking for:

[image: Community specific reasons]