# Clarify what "standard flags" means on "What is Flagging?"

Tags: feature-request, flags, help-center

One of the canned responses for a declined flag is:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](/help/privileges/flag-posts)

However, the help center doesn't really explain what is considered as "standard flags", thus users may think that "in need of moderator intervention" is also a standard flag. Searching for ["standard"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=standard) on the help center also doesn't return any result for "standard flags".

This may result in users new to flagging getting their flags declined, trying to learn from the help center, but still don't understand the meaning:

- [What is the guidance for using "Standard Flags?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290507/what-is-the-guidance-for-using-standard-flags)
- [Are unhelpful flag responses automated?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/are-unhelpful-flag-responses-automated)
- [Missing flag option "Should be closed" resulted in rejected flag "Please familiarise yourself with standard flags"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346425/missing-flag-option-should-be-closed-resulted-in-rejected-flag-please-familia)

Thus, can the help center be made clear about "standard flags"?

---

[Can /help/privileges/flag-posts be updated to reflect the new flagging reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346429/can-help-privileges-flag-posts-be-updated-to-reflect-the-new-flagging-reasons) is related but still didn't clarify what "standard flags" means.